# How to use Spring Boot 3.2.0 with MySQL database and JpaRepository @Query has boolean comparison

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am planning to migrate spring boot from 2.7.1 to 3.2.0.

It's my model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tutorials")
public class Tutorial {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "published")
    private Boolean published;

    // setters and getters
}
```

And my repository:

```
public interface TutorialRepository extends JpaRepository<Tutorial, Long> {     
    @Query("select t from Tutorial t where t.published IS TRUE")
    List<Tutorial> getTutorial();
}
```

And My rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TutorialController {

@Autowired
TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

@GetMapping("/tutorials")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tutorial>> getAllTutorials(@RequestParam(required = false) String title) {
    try {
        List<Tutorial> tutorials = new ArrayList<Tutorial>();

        if (title == null)
            tutorialRepository.findAll().forEach(tutorials::add);
        else
            tutorialRepository.findByTitleContaining(title).forEach(tutorials::add);

        if (tutorials.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(tutorials, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}


@GetMapping("/tutorial/published")
public ResponseEntity<List<Tutorial>> findByTutorialPublished() {
    try {
        List<Tutorial> tutorials = tutorialRepository.getTutorial();
        tutorials.forEach(System.out::println);
        if (tutorials.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(tutorials, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

}
```

And for database configuration, I create application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

When I check the api 'http://localhost:8080/api/tutorial/published', got 500 internal server error. Means, fails to execute JPA query with boolean comparison. But its working in spring boot 2.7.1.

I again tried using hibernate to 6.4.0 in pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bezkoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-mysql</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Apis CRUD using Spring Data JPA</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
    <hibernate.version>6.4.0.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

No hope.

In Eclipse IDE, I can see following warning: (no issues)

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.10.1 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.13.0
ANTLR Runtime version 4.10.1 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.13.0
```

But the error in eclipse while testing the api as follows:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.BadJpqlGrammarException: Line 1:44 mismatched input 'IS' expecting {<EOF>, ',', '+', '-', '/', '||', '[', '.', AND, '*', BY, DAY, EPOCH, EXCEPT, GROUP, HOUR, INTERSECT, MINUTE, MONTH, NANOSECOND, OR, ORDER, QUARTER, SECOND, UNION, WEEK, YEAR}; Bad JPQL grammar [select t from Tutorial t where t.published IS TRUE]
```

Please guide me to move forward with Spring boot 3.2.0 ?

Comment: Have you tried to set `where t.published   = true` yet ?

Comment: Thanks. Its working. but  ```<> true```  otherwise ```!= true``` is not working.  Before I have used ```t.published IS NOT TRUE```. So I am using ```(t.published   is null or t.published   = false)``` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA Query Methods, like in your case `findByPublishedTrue()` so that the method name will be translated into the JPA query.

```java
public interface TutorialRepository extends JpaRepository<Tutorial, Long> {     
    List<Tutorial> findByPublishedTrue();
}
```

**Note:** you don't have to use `@Query` on top your method.

If you want to know more about JPA Query Methods, check the official documentation here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html

Comment: It's a sample for demonstrating```where t.published IS TRUE``` or```IS FALSE``` or```IS NOT TRUE``` or ```IS NOT FALSE``` is not working  in Spring boot 3.2 with Hibernate 6.4.0 (ANTLR 4.13.0). But our actual JPA Query has JOIN multiple entities with boolean comparisons.

Comment: @ajeshbaby JPA Query Method is actually going to generate SQL query as `t.published = true`, not `t.published IS TRUE`

Comment: I saw ```t.published = true``` is woring, but why ```t.published != true```  or ```t.published <> true``` is not working. While I am using Spring 2.7.1, I have used ```t.published is true``` and ```t.published is not true```. Do you know, instead of ```t.published is not true``` now I am using in sring 3.2.0 as ```(t.published is null or t.published = false)```

Answer (score 0):

check https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation for query syntax.
The error you got "**Bad JPQL grammar** [select t from Tutorial t where t.published IS TRUE]" clearly says JPA query syntax is not correct.

also <hibernate.version>6.4.0.Final</hibernate.version> is not coming default with spring boot 3.2.0 hence the warning is coming because of incorrect version used to compile and run the hibernate queries. remove it to use default hibernate version which comes with spring boot 3.2.0 to resolve this warning

Comment: I know about Query creation from method names. My question is specific to: why ```t.published is true``` is not working in spring boot 3.2.0 (but its working in spring boot 2.7.1).  Do you know, instead of ```t.published is not true``` now I am using in spring boot 3.2.0 as ```(t.published is null or t.published = false)```. 

It's a sample for demonstrating ```where t.published IS TRUE``` or ```IS FALSE``` or ```IS NOT TRUE``` or ```IS NOT FALSE``` is not working in Spring boot 3.2.0. But our actual JPA Query has complex JOIN multiple entities with boolean comparisons.

Comment: Different Spring versions use different versions of hibernate underneath. I suggest to read hibernate migration guide for this. There's a lot of stuff changed with hibernate 6 which comes with spring boot 3.2.x. other way is to use naive query =true flag. So as to match the query your db provider is expecting. Finally you can still stick to old version of hibernate just for time being to test your application migration on remaining things.